# Replacing a '<br>' in a textarea and sending the proceeding text to a lower line (breaking the line)

Tags: javascript, html, simple-html-dom

So I'm trying to make an html file, where I collect input from a user, which is displayed in a div that is separated from the  which is collecting the actual input.

```
setInterval(div.innerHTML = textarea.value );
```

I have made it so that every time the user presses the enter key, on the div display, it adds a 
 tag to go to the next line.

The issue is that I want to be able to take the contents in the div and paste them into another textarea.

`textareaTwo.value = div.innerHTML;`

Unfortunately, the 
 tags that were being used to break the lines for display in the div appear in the second textarea.

Is there anyway I can remove the 
 tags and replace them with actual line breaks in the second textarea when I move text from the div to the second textarea?

Comment: You can use textareaTwo= textareaTwo.replace(/\n/g,'<br>');

Comment: @Grumpy and run a for loop to see how many times I would run it. Thanks a lot!